# issue with textbox event handlers

Tags: c#, wpf, event-handling

I am still learning how to do with event handler. 
**What I want is:** When I click the txtMonday to get focused, then I click the remove button to clear this selected textbox. 
**Problem is:** when I click the remove button for the selected textbox, all the unselected textboxes are clear. I only want to remove the selected textbox. How to solve this problem? Your code example much appreciated. Thanks! I am using WPF and C#.

```
    private void btnRemoveClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox text = new TextBox();
        text.GotFocus += new RoutedEventHandler(txtMonday_GotFocus);
           txtMonday.Clear();


        text.GotFocus += new RoutedEventHandler(txtTuesday_GotFocus);
           txtTuesday.Clear();

    }

    private void txtMonday_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void txtTuesday_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Comment: wont this add the event handler numerous times?

Comment: You are very much misunderstanding how events and objects work. You have a lot of reading to do. Your btnRemoveClick function creates a new text box (not visible), adds an event for gotFocus, clears the monday textbox, adds the same event again, and clears the tuseday box. passing the event handler is a very strange thing to do here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do what you want. I suggest you do some more studying about C# though, as your code shows some fundamental misunderstandings.

```
//you'll need a variable to store the last focused textbox.
TextBox txtLast;

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    //add an event for all the textboxes so that you can track when one of them gets focus.
    txtSunday.GotFocus += txt_GotFocus;
    txtMonday.GotFocus += txt_GotFocus;
    txtTuesday.GotFocus += txt_GotFocus;
    txtWednesday.GotFocus += txt_GotFocus;
    txtThursday.GotFocus += txt_GotFocus;
    txtFriday.GotFocus += txt_GotFocus;
    txtSaturday.GotFocus += txt_GotFocus;

    //default to clearing sunday to avoid exception 
    //you could also let it clear a new TextBox(), but this is wasteful. Ideally, 
    //you would handle this case gracefully with an if statement, but I will leave that 
    //as an exercise to the reader. 
    txtLast = txtSunday;
}

private void txt_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //whenever you click a textbox, this event gets called. 
    //e.source is the textbox, but since it is is just an "Object" we need to cast it to a TextBox
    txtLast = e.Source as TextBox;
}

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //this will clear the textbox which last had focus. If you click a button, the current textbox loses focus. 
    txtLast.Clear();
}
```